# Could not load file or assembly microsoft.sqlserver.management.sdk.sfc

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Receiving below error message in Visual Studio 2008 while creating a connection for database.

> could not load file or assembly 
>   'microsoft.sqlserver.management.sdk.sfc ,Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

I am trying to create database internally i.e. `.mdf` file and store it in the `App_data` folder.
But I'm not able to create the connection.

Please help me to sort out the issue quickly.

Comment: Connection string?  Jet driver perhaps?  version?  Is office or access installed?

Comment: Problem has been now solved by installing below three setups ...     Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=123721&clcid=0x409

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Objects - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=123708&clcid=0x409

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=123717&clcid=0x409

Answer (score 6):

You can download these files from Microsoft website.

1.Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types

2.Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Objects

3.Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client.

After installing the above three files try to connect your application with sql server database and if still you got the same error message then don't worry and close your application then start it again and you will be able to connect it.